# Angular ng-repeat doesn't show items

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have worked with angularjs before but for some reason I cannot seem to get it to iterate through my array.

If I look in browser's console I can see that its not empty

Here is my code.

**AngularJS**

```
$scope.Clients = [];
$scope.LoadClients = function () {
    $.get('/Client/GetClientList').then((d) => {
        angular.copy(d.results, $scope.Clients);
        console.log($scope.Clients);
        $("#clientTable").DataTable();

    });
};
```

**HTML**

```
<table class="table table-bordered" id="clientTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Active</th>
            <th>Nr. Branches</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="client in Clients">
            <td ng-bind="client.Name"></td>
            <td class="text-center" ng-bind="client.Active"></td>
            <td class="text-center" ng-bind="client.Branches.length" ng-click="ViewBranches($index)"></td>
            <td class="text-center">
                <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" ng-click="ViewClient($index)">
                        <span class="fa fa-eye"></span>
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs" ng-click="ViewBranches($index)">
                        <span class="fa fa-list"></span>
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" ng-click="DeleteClient($index)">
                        <span class="fa fa-trash"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Use angular `$http` to make request. jQuery `$.get` changes scope outside of angular context and requires using `$apply` to notify angular to run a view digest

Comment: Also suggest using angular datatables module instead of initializing plugin in controller

Comment: Thanks, I overlooked that (facepalm)

Comment: Does it solve?? how? @Gericke

Comment: @Saeed.Ataee : using `$http` :)

Comment: @Saeed.Ataee I used ajax get instead of using angular's $http service which will then complete the cycle and do bindings. If you use normal ajax get you need to use $apply which force angular to complete the cycle

Comment: @Saeed.Ataee if you have a problem yourself ask a new question. Posting comments about non related issue is not appropriate

Comment: @Saeed.Ataee your only problem in that demo is you don't have any cells (`<td>` or `<th>`) in `<tr>`. Can't output text directly as child of `<tr>`